# How to include .cat and .inf file in Visual studio 2012 application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, usb, device-driver

I am developing a hmi for a usb device in visual studio 2012 and I want to include usb device drivers in my program installation. I do have .cat and .inf file of the usb device but how should I include them in my hmi installation so that user doesn't have to prompt windows to search for the folders.

thanks in advance for helping me out,

Veeru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what kind of installation technology you are using; Visual Studio provides both "ClickOnce" and "Setup Projects".

With ClickOnce, I don't think it is possible to install drivers.

With a Setup Project, you will have to make a custom action that calls SetupOEMCopyInf.  To make that custom action, you have to compile a Win32 DLL using C or C++.